# error in overloading ostream operator c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am making overloading ostream/istream operator function friend function of my class but it gives error :
ostream does not name a type.
without or with header file `#include<iostream>` it gives error

```
date.h:24:9: error: ‘ostream’ does not name a type friend ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, Date &today);
```

Comment: `std::ostream` or `using namespace std;`

Comment: `std::ostream`. `using namespace std;` generally bad.

Comment: didn't get your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name `ostream` is located in the `std`-namespace, so you need to introduce that name. The least intrusive way is to just qualify it explicitly:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<< ....
       ^^^
```

Another way is using a `using`- or `using namespace`-directive. They allow you to import the name/s to the rest of the translation unit:

```
using std::ostream; // cherry-pick the names
friend ostream& operator<< ....
```

or

```
using namespace std; // fire a shotgun with a huge and growing bunch of names
friend ostream& operator<< ....
```

These have advantages and disadvantages:

- The name becomes shorter and might be better readable in the context
- Name-Clashes may arise when other namespaces define the same names (consider e.g. `std::pow` vs. `awesome_math_lib::pow`).

An agreed upon rule-of-thumb for good C++-code is to never use `using` or `using namespace` in the global namespace in an header file, and with care in source files.

Many also agree that `std::` is so short and standard, that they never use `using` or `using namespace` on it (except within functions) and just stick to typing `std::...`.

Comment: Another consideration is not to use `friend` at all.  I tend to define a public member function in a class and use it.  Example: `std::ostream &printTo(std::ostream &out) { ... }` is the member function of `myclass` and then `std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, myclass &me) {return me.printTo(out); }` is the function.  That preserves the privacy of the implementation of `myclass` better than using `friend` in my view.

Comment: @Edward: I am not sure about it. With `friend` you explicitly qualify a certain function and only that function for private access, a function that can be considered part of the interface. I don't see an actual difference to adding a `printTo` function, except the latter increases the size of the interface and therefore tends to icnrease the potential for tighter coupling.

Comment: Oh, and the wording seems inaccurate. Serialization is not necessarily printing. Consider cloning an object over the network using stream-operators; I wouldn't find `printOn` too intuitive.

Comment: the problem is that the `friend` function can access *everything* within the class including protected and private data members.  This is easily avoided by providing a member function.  If the name bothers you, choose something else.  I find that 99% of the time my use is for printing, and so have been using `printTo` as a name for such functions for around 20 years.

Comment: @Edward: But basically, both solutions are equivalent. A friend function is as much part of the interface as a member function; both have the same degree of coupling (read: private access) to the class, and so both can do the same harm. However, the non-friend function variant imposes a bigger interface onto the class' clients (the difference might be small, but is is there), and therefore, apart from otherwise being identical, does provoke tighter coupling between client code and the class. And of course you have the additional problem of choosing a proper name in the ostream-case...

Comment: ... . To summarize: Yes, the friend function has private access. But so has the member function.

Comment: Quoting Stroustrup in _The C++ Programming Language, Fourth Edition_, under the heading of "advice" at the end of chapter 19, "Prefer member functions to friend functions for granting access to the implementation of a class."

Comment: @Edward: Good general advice that misses the target here. To make your class comply to the stream-IO interface, you _need_ to overload `operator<<(ostream&,T)`; there is no way doing that as a member. You don't enhance the situation at any means by introducing a new member _and_ an overload. But when we now prefer quotes over arguments: “You cannot reason people out of a position that they did not reason themselves into.” -- Ben Goldacre (found on http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/tag/argument)

Comment: @Edward: I am just presenting reasons why I think a friend is better in this case. My target was not being right.

Answer (score 1):

Change your declaration and implementation to use the fully qualified name for the type:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Date& d)
```

Avoid using `using namespace std;` as it can (and likely will) cause naming conflicts - especially when used in header files (a **big** no-no).

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the namespace `std` using

```
std::ostream
```

in your code.

Another method is

```
using namespace std;
```

but it is not preferred.

Answer (score -1):

You need to include header `<iostream>` and either use qualified name

```
std::ostream
```

or include directive

```
using std::ostream;
```

or even

```
using namespace std;
```

Standard class `ostream` for output streams is declared in name space `std`.

Comment: please discourage & warn using using namespace std, when mentioning it as alternative.